# Setting a variable to a list name

Tags: vba, list, for-loop

I'm trying to generate lists named by a variable in FOR loop like this:

```
    For i = 0 To 5

        Dim list(i) As List(Of Integer)

    Next
```

But it doesn't work. I cant use those lists further on like: list2.add(100)..

Any ideas?

Comment: VBA doesn't have "lists" - are you maybe using VB.NET ?

Answer (score 0):

In VB variables can't be declared dynamically by name.

The Dim statement is executed at compile time and defines the name and optionally the type of a variable. Th default type of a variable is `Variant` which can hold any type of value.

Of course you can define an array of lists:

```
Dim lists(0 to 5) As List(Of Integer)
```

and use them like:

```
lists(2).Add(100)
```

(Using your example, which may be VB.NET rather than VB.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Redim Preseve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) statement, it allows you to change the array size on the fly.

Something in the spirit of this code:

```
Option Base 1
Dim list(1) As Integer
Dim count As Integer

'Add 100 to the end of the array
count=count+1
Redim Preserve list(count)
list(count)=100


'Add 200 to the end of the array
count=count+1
Redim Preserve list(count)
list(count)=200


'Print all items
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(list) To UBound(list)
     Debug.Print (list(i))
Next i
'Output: 100,200
```

Should help you get the desired behavior using `VBA`